# Selenium :After launching a website how could we check if the right page is launched

Tags: selenium, html, launch

In Selenium :After launching a website how  could we  check if the right page is launched or not.

Example: 
If I want to launch `www.google.com`,after running the code how do I check if the same page has been launched.

I used,

```
Assert.assertEquals("Correct web page",driver.findElement(By.Xpath("<xpath of one of the element in the page>")).isDisplayed ());
```

After running the program, I got the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<Correct web page> but was:<true>
```

Comment: Provide the URL as a parameter and after the page has loaded assert that the `driver.getCUrrentUrl()` equals the URL that you provided initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to assert for correct page loaded, most used are the assert for correct url loaded and page title.

**Assert for Correct URL Loaded:**

```
String expectedUrl = "https://www.google.com";
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(expectedUrl);
try{
  Assert.assertEquals(expectedUrl, driver.getCurrentUrl());
  System.out.println("Navigated to correct webpage");
}
catch(Throwable pageNavigationError){
  System.out.println("Didn't navigate to correct webpage");
}
```

**Assert for page title:**

```
String expectedTitle = "Google";
String expectedUrl = "https://www.google.com";
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(expectedUrl);
try{
  Assert.assertEquals(expectedTitle, driver.getTitle());
  System.out.println("Navigated to correct webpage");
}
catch(Throwable pageNavigationError){
  System.out.println("Didn't navigate to correct webpage");
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm if the actual  is same as expected we do not get to see anything in the console unless we use a println statements .. is this correct ?

Comment: We can give print statement for both the cases. See my edited response.

Comment: Just click on the hollow right symbol below the voting icon

Comment: Thanks Vignesh. @user3702778: In case you need more info on how to accept answer visit : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Comment: "Assert for Correct URL Loaded" section is what I was looking for and it works. Thanks!