# check if a page is opened, Java Selenium

Tags: java, webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver, how can I check if a page is opened or not after clicking a specific button ? Maybe someone recommend me useful resources where I can read about it. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777134/selenium-after-launching-a-website-how-could-we-check-if-the-right-page-is-laun

Comment: Maybe enuf to check the page's title? webDriver.getTitle()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium :After launching a website how could we check if the right page is launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777134/selenium-after-launching-a-website-how-could-we-check-if-the-right-page-is-laun)

Answer (score 6):

You can check with the title of the page. If you get title of the page, it means page is opened.

```
String expectedTitle = "Stack Overflow";
String url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(url);
if(driver.getTitle() != null && driver.getTitle().contains(expectedTitle)){
  System.out.println("Web page is opened");
}
else{
  System.out.println("Web page could not open.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with some content of the page.

```
public boolean checkIfPageArrived(String... testText) throws Throwable {
    boolean found = false;
    for (String text : testText) {
        found = $$(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + text + "')]").isEmpty();
        if (found) {
            break;
        }
    }

return found;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by  isElementPresent ?